# Approximate n^th power convolution

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, convolution

> What is the approximation for $n^{th}$ convolution power (n-fold convolution) $g(x)=  \underbrace{p * p * p * \cdots * p * p}_n$ with respsect to $p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a probability density function?

I have solved this problem for large $n$ since I can use central limit theorem and approximate $g(x)$ to a Gaussian. I am not sure how to find the answer for the general case. Is there an approximation for $n^{th}$ convolution power (n-fold convolution)? Read more about convolution power [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_power).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. $f(x)$, which I changed it to $p(x)$, is a probability density function.

Comment: There probably isn't much that can be said about small $n$, except for the nice relation between Fourier transforms and convolution.

Comment: (By the way, you can't quite approximate it with a Gaussian for all $p$, only "nice" $p$.)

Comment: Thanks. But can you please tell me why?

Comment: See the link you provided - you need $p$ to have a mean and variance, which not every $p$ will have. Specifically, it is possible for $p$ not to be $L^2$ even though it is a probability density function, because it can take lots of large values on very short intervals. Something like: $$p(x)=\begin{cases}2^n&x\in[n,n+1/4^n], n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ This is a probability density  function which is not $L^2$.

Comment: It is the inverse Fourier transform of the $n$-th power of the Fourier transform of $p$.

Comment: $g(x)=  \underbrace{p * p * p * \cdots * p * p}_n$

take the fourier transform: $\hat{g}(x)=\underbrace{\hat{p}\hat{p}\hat{p}\cdots\hat{p}\hat{p}}_n=\left(\hat{p}\right)^n$; then just take the inverse fourier transform